# Is there aberration of sound?

Tags: acoustics

I watched a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFNgd3pitAI) by Scienclic showing a spaceship experiencing a peculiar optical illusion when going faster and faster in space, I wonder is there a version for the sound? Like I'm driving faster and faster on a busy traffic then I think most of the sound are coming from ahead despite the sources are actually at the sides?

Comment: Link to the mentioned optical illusion youtube video ?

Comment: Briefly, I think the answer is yes, the aberration phenomena applies to any wave including sound. (Same goes for the closely related Doppler effect.)

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.13661 "Sound and light Doppler effects" (also aberration is discussed)